# Initialize custom ko.computed in class

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, scope

I don't know if it's possible, but I would like to achieve something like this:

```
function templateCheck(Properties,ComputedFunction){
   var self = this;
   self.Prop1 = ko.observable(Properties.Prop1);
   self.CustomCaltulation = ko.computed(ComputedFunction);
   return {
      returningValue: self.CustomCalculation
   }
}

// This doesn't work
var test = new templateCheck({Prop1: "something"},function(){ return self.Prop1(); })
// Error: TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'Prop1'
```

Thus far I'm unsuccessful to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a 'self' variable. It's actually making it harder for you, since 'self' is not defined outside the context of templateCheck, as you found out. The trick is to use the 'owner' property of the computed variable, which sets the 'meaning' of `this`

```
function templateCheck(Properties, ComputedFunction){
    this.Prop1 = ko.observable(Properties.Prop1);
    this.CustomCalculation = ko.computed({
        read: ComputedFunction,
        owner: this
    });
    return {
        returningValue: this.CustomCalculation
    };
}

var test = new templateCheck({Prop1: "something"},function(){ return this.Prop1(); })
```

I do wonder why you are trying to do this though. It feels a bit like a code smell to me. Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Brilliant. Just few minutes ago I implemented this with `.apply()` method ,now I will use this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the self variable is not defined in the context of your function.

```
function templateCheck(Properties){
   var self = this;
   self.Prop1 = ko.observable(Properties.Prop1);

    self.setComputedFunction(computedFunction) {
        self.customCalculation = ko.computed(computedFunction);     
    }
}

var template = new templateCheck({Prop1: "something"});
var myComputedFunction = function(){ return template.Prop1(); };
template.setComputedFunction(myComputedFunction);

var test=template.customCalculation;
```

Comment: While this will work, I feel its not very optimal. It makes constructing the object complex, and it can potentially lead to memory issues.

Comment: what kind of memory issues ?

Comment: You're creating a reference to `var template` inside `myComputedFunction`. So now `template` cannot be garbage collected as long as `myComputedFunction` is referenced somewhere. While in this bit of code it doesn't cause issues, I do consider it bad practise to create a reference like this if it's not needed, because you're influencing the lifetime of another object unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You have written `self.CustomCaltulation` instead of `self.CustomCalculation` . This might not be the issue in your case but soon i see your question i found this.